# Flutter| list is populating same data over as state is changing

Tags: flutter, dart, google-cloud-firestore

I'm trying to save a list of documents in **approveList[]** if approve variable in firestore is true and populate that list in a grid view later. But a problem occurs when I switch between navBar pages. each time I navigate to a new page, all data in approve list is being duplicated again in **approveList**, Like if approve have [a,b], after changing to another page it has [a,b,a,b]

Here is the code where approve list is getting data:

```
List<Object> approveList = [];
Future getRestaurantsList() async {
var doc;
var collection = await 
FirebaseFirestore.instance.collection('Restaurants').where('status', isEqualTo: 
"Approved");
var querySnapshots =
    await collection.get().then((value) => value.docs.forEach((element) {
          print(element.reference);
          approveList.add(element.reference.id);
        }));

}
```

this where im using getRestaurantList

```
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
return Scaffold(
  body: getBody(),
  bottomNavigationBar: _buildBottomBar(),
);
}
Widget getBody() {
List<Widget> pages = [
  Scaffold(
    appBar: AppBar(
      bottomOpacity: 0.0,
      elevation: 0.0,
      backgroundColor: Colors.white,
      automaticallyImplyLeading: false,
      title: Text("Approved Restaurants", style: TextStyle(color: Colors.deepOrange),),
      leading: IconButton(onPressed: () { Navigator.pop(context); }, icon: Icon(Icons.arrow_back_ios,color: Colors.black,),),

    ),
    body: Container(
      child: Column(
        crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
        children: <Widget>[
          Expanded(
              child: FutureBuilder(
                  future: getRestaurantsList(),
                  builder: (context, snapshot) {
                    return ListView.builder(
                        itemCount: approveList.length,
                        itemBuilder: (context, index) {
                          return ListTile(
                            title: ApprovedRestaurants(documentId: approveList[index] as String, Index: index ,),
                          );
                        });
                  }))
        ],
      ),
    ),
  ),
  Scaffold(
    appBar: AppBar(
      bottomOpacity: 0.0,
      elevation: 0.0,
      backgroundColor: Colors.white,
      automaticallyImplyLeading: false,
      title: Text("Pending Approvals", style: TextStyle(color: Colors.deepOrange),),
      leading: IconButton(onPressed: () { Navigator.pop(context); }, icon: Icon(Icons.arrow_back_ios,color: Colors.black,),),

    ),
    body: Container(
      child: Column(
        crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
        children: <Widget>[
          SizedBox(),
          Expanded(
              child: FutureBuilder(
                  future: getRequestList(),
                  builder: (context, snapshot) {
                    return ListView.builder(
                        itemCount: requestList.length,
                        itemBuilder: (context, index) {
                          return ListTile(
                            title: RequestRestaurants(documentId: requestList[index] as String,),
                          );
                        });
                  }))
        ],
      ),
    ),
  ),

  // Container(
  //   alignment: Alignment.center,
  //   child: Text("Messages",style: TextStyle(fontSize: 25,fontWeight: FontWeight.bold),),
  // ),
  // Container(
  //   alignment: Alignment.center,
  //   child: Text("Settings",style: TextStyle(fontSize: 25,fontWeight: FontWeight.bold),),
  // ),
];
return IndexedStack(
  index: _currentIndex,
  children: pages,
);
}
```

there is one more function right after getRestaurantList which is approveList() which is doing the same functioning

Comment: Can you include more details where and how you are using `getRestaurantsList` and `getRestaurantsList()`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can clear the list before adding, this will solve the issue

```dart
List<Object> approveList = [];
Future getRestaurantsList() async {
  approveList.clear();
```

But while you are using FutureBuilder, create a future variable on state class like

```dart
late final future  = getRestaurantsList();
```

And use it on

```dart
child: FutureBuilder(
     future: future,
```

It would be better to return list from future instead of storing on another variable.

More about using [`FutureBuilder`](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/FutureBuilder-class.html)

Comment: It worked, thanks, but the part where getRestaurantsList() is stored in the variable as you suggested, didn't work.

Comment: I prefer creating different context/widget for page, The second approach  mostly used on stateful widget to avoid unnecessary calling the API